# How to autoplay iframe youtube on webview android

Tags: android, iframe, youtube, android-webview

I have read everything related to this issue and nothing worked so far :

- Add "autoplay=1" parameter to the end of the URL (like `https://www.youtube.com/embed/%s?autoplay=1`), `%s` being the video id.
- It seems Google disabled it by default : https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=159336
- Javascript injection won't work :

  ```
  mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
      public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
          mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].play(); })()");
      }

  });
  mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
  ```

Any new working solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, no longer allows autoplay in the internal webview of Android.
However, you can try implement autoplay using the YouTube API or iframe api.

1. Using Native SDK
   https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads/
2. Using iframe API
   https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference

Answer (score 0):

You can try issue a single click on the webview

```
@Override
public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
    float x = view.getWidth() / 2;
    float y = view.getHeight() / 2;
    MotionEvent motionEventDown = MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, x, y, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 0.5f, 0.5f, InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN, 0);
    MotionEvent motionEventUp = MotionEvent.obtain(SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 200, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP, x, y, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0, 0.5f, 0.5f, InputDevice.SOURCE_TOUCHSCREEN, 0);
    view.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEventDown);
    view.dispatchTouchEvent(motionEventUp);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

A little late but I hope this helps.

After your youtube embeded url page is finished loading run this:-

```
yourWebView.loadUrl("javascript:(function() { document.getElementsByClassName('ytp-large-play-button ytp-button')[0].click(); })()");
```